# How to wrap any mobile number's into Anchor tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tel

I have one html page where all data's are coming dynamically with some mobile numbers.
How can I wrap all mobile numbers into anchor tag using javascript.

Example: `<a href="tel:+91 9999999999">+91 9999999999</a>`

HTML:

```
<p>Tel: +022 23334976</p>
<p>Tel: +91 8976817722 </p>
.
.
.
.
<p><b>Tel:</b> +91 8976817725 </p>
```

Please help me to write common js for handling above type of html page.

Comment: Please provide code that generates your 'dynamic' data.

Comment: @mparryy Dynamic means I am getting above type of Html code from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML.replace(/(?:<b>)?Tel:(?:<\/b>)? ?(\+[0-9]* [0-9]*)/ig, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
```

Comment: thanks for the help, based on your code I created a fiddle ie. http://fiddle.jshell.net/ck59pqhj/